# How to ignore CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT in a python executable on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

I have been searching or an answer, but found nothing sepcific, except for the windows service part.
Is it possible to ignore the LOGOFF signal that Windows sends, when a user is logging off, and keep my python executalbe ( py2exe ) running , besides using windows service?

Or any other way I can keep it running even after an user has logged off? User does NOT have administrator priviliges.

Comment: If you actually want the program to keep running, even though there is nobody logged in, you must use a service.

Answer (score 1):

Only services receive `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`. From MSDN:

> Note that this signal is received only
>   by services. Interactive applications are terminated at logoff, so
>   they are not present when the system sends this signal.

Since your process is not a service, it will not even receive that signal, hence, it is not possible to "ignore" it.